# Trying to calculate correct returns and set a constraints on the max and min invested in each asset using 'quad_form'

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I am trying to hack together some code that looks like it should print our risk and returns of a portfolio, but the first return is 0.00, and that can't be right. Here's the code that I'm testing.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [[130000, 150000, 190000, 200000], [100000, 200000, 300000, 900000], [350000, 450000, 890000, 20000], [400000, 10000, 500000, 600000]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['HOSPITAL', 'HOTEL', 'STADIUM', 'SUBWAY'])
 
# print dataframe.
data
```

That gives me this data frame.

[image]

```
symbols = data.columns

# convert daily stock prices into daily returns
returns = data.pct_change()

r = np.asarray(np.mean(returns, axis=1))
r = np.nan_to_num(r)

C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))
C = np.nan_to_num(C)

# print expected returns and risk
for j in range(len(symbols)):
    print ('%s: Exp ret = %f, Risk = %f' %(symbols[j],r[j], C[j,j]**0.5))
```

The result is this.

[image]

The hospital risk and return can't be zero. That doesn't make sense. Something is off here, but I'm not sure what.

Finally, I am trying to optimize the portfolio. So, I hacked together this code.

```
# Number of variables
n = len(data)

# The variables vector
x = Variable(n)

# The minimum return
req_return = 0.02

# The return
ret = r.T*x

# The risk in xT.Q.x format
risk = quad_form(x, C)

# The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0])

try:
    prob.solve()
    print ("Optimal portfolio")
    print ("----------------------")
    for s in range(len(symbols)):
       print (" Investment in {} : {}% of the portfolio".format(symbols[s],round(100*x.value[s],2)))
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("Exp ret = {}%".format(round(100*ret.value,2)))
    print ("Expected risk    = {}%".format(round(100*risk.value**0.5,2)))
except:
    print ("Error")
```

It seems to run but I don't know how to add a constraint. I want to invest at least 5% in every asset and don't invest more than 40% in any one asset. How can I add a constraint to do that?

The idea comes from this link.

https://tirthajyoti.github.io/Notebooks/Portfolio_optimization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea from the link, they skip the NaN row from the monthly return dataframe, and after converting the return to a matrix, the following step is transposing the matrix, that is the step you are missing hence you are getting the returns and risk as 0 for Hospital. You might want to add this line 
`C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns.dropna().transpose()))`to skip the first NaN line. This should give you the correct Returns and Risk values.

As for your second question, i had a quick glance into the class definition of cxpy Problem class and there doesnt seem to be a provision for add constraints. The function was programmed to solve equations based on the Minimizing or Maximizing constraint given to it.

For a work around you might want to try taking the outputs and then capping the investment to 40% and and the remaining you distribute it among other ventures proportionally. Example lets say it tells you to invest 5%, 80% and 15% of your assets in A, B and C. You could cap investment in B to 40% and the part remainder of the asset (5/(5+15))*40 = 10% more into A and 30% of your total investing asset more ,into B.

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert in finance, i am just stating my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty helpful. I added dropna and transpose, and I'm getting a risk calculation but still 0 for returns. I'm certain the return is not 0, but I don't know how to fix it. I found a resource that talks about constraints for the 'quad_form' function, but I don't know how to implement it.  https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96864/cvxpy.quad_form

Comment: did you try x<0.4 in your constraints?

Comment: I just entered that right after the line with x = Variable(n), and I got this: NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, i meant update the line prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0]) to prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0,x>=0.4])

Comment: Yeap, yeap, that work. Thanks a ton for that! Very useful!